# Kubernets Connection refused when using IP but not when using localhost

Tags: kubernetes

I deployed a NetCore 6 service in Kubernets that runs on port 5000. The problem is that the pod is not accepting external connection (I get Connection refused) but if I open the pod an Do telnet to localhost 5000 it works but in the same pod telnet to the ip addreess on port 5000 it does not work.

Thanks for your help!!

[image]

Comment: please paste you asp.netcore startup log.

Comment: Hello David. What is the output of 'kubectl logs yourPodName -n yourNamespace'? It seems there is a configuration problem with your NetCore app.  Try ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://0.0.0.0:5000 or ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5000 or UseUrls("http://*:5000") in Programs.cs file.

Comment: check this command output to see which all IP's are listening on port 5000.

netstat -tunlp |grep 5000

Mostly you might be listening on 127.0.0.1. If so then you can't telnet on 172.*.*.* IP.